# With Kendo-UI-mobile, how do I enhance a page after updating it's content?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a mobile app that will allow a user to tap on an item in a list, which will then populate a 'details' page, and navigate to that page.

When the user taps the back button, and selects another item in the list, the details page is updated with the new content, but the markup loses all kendo-ui-mobile styling.

Is there a way to trigger the enhanced content after the markup has been updated?

Here is my code (the relevant bits):

**index.html**

```
<div id="details" data-role="view" data-title="Details" data-layout="default">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a id="back-button" class="nav-button" data-align="left" data-role="backbutton">Back</a>
            <span data-role="view-title"></span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="details_body"></div>
</div>
```

**router.js**

```
$('.listItemLink').live('click', function(e) {
    require(['views/companyDetailsView'], function (companyDetailsView) {
        var view = new companyDetailsView({
            model: companyDetails,
            el: $('#details_body')
        }).render(function(el) {
            app.navigate('#details');
            app.hideLoading();
        }).el;
    });

});
```

**companyDetailsView.js**

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'underscore',
    'models/companyModel',
    'text!templates/companyDetails.html'
], function (Backbone, _, companyModel, tmpl) {
    'use strict';

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: _.template(tmpl),
        render: function (callback) {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            callback(this.$el);
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code, you shouldn't really have to do anything.  Here is a quick sample using a kendo listview on one page, and then a simple display of properties on a second.  http://jsbin.com/aZEXEZaG/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. the example you provided works perfectly, but I'm not using kendo-ui data-binding, instead I'm updating the markup directly, using the results of an Ajax call.